# How can I get a variable form a Zend SQL resultset?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

How do I get a variable from a zend query?

I have a Query that will return one record.  I then want to get a field from this record and set it as a variable.  Any thoughts?

Query:
    public function getProContestedReview($contest_review_id)
    {
        $adapter = $this->getAdapter();

```
    $sql = new Sql($adapter);
    $select = $sql->select();
    $select->from('contest_review_table') 
        ->join(array('review' => 'review_table'),
             'review.review_id = contest_review_table.review_id')
        ->join(array('friend' => 'friend_table'),
             'friend.friend_id = review.friend_id')
        ->join(array('pro' => 'pro_table'),
             'pro.pro_id = review.pro_id')
        ->join(array('verification' => 'verification_status'),
             'verification.status_id = contest_review_table.contest_review_status_id')           
        ->where(array(
            'contest_review_id' => $contest_review_id,
            ));      
    $selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
    $resultSet = $adapter->query($selectString, $adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
    return $resultSet;       
}
```

I would like to set the variable $friend_id to the friend id from the query.

```
$friend_id = $this->getProContestedReview->friend_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to do this and it works. $friend_id = $proContestedReview[0]['friend_id'];

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

if you use

```
vardump($resultSet);
```

you can see what is exactly in the returned result.

You could probably use

```
$friend_id = $resultSet['friend_id'];
```

or

```
$proContestedReview = $this->getProContestedReview($some_id_variable);
$friend_id = $proContestedReview['friend_id'];
```

Comment: I get a 'cannot get instance of table' error.  All my queries are on a different php file "administratorSide".  How do I integrate above with this $reviewInformation = new AdministratorSide($dbAdapter);

Comment: I used var_dump and see the array.  However when I use $friend_id = $proContestedReview['friend_id']; I get an Undefined index: friend_id however I see it in the var dump

Answer (score 0):

```
$resultSet = $resultSet->current();
```

the `$resultSet` now should be a instance of `ArrayObject`, so just `var_dump($resultSet)` to see exactly what you have inside.

you can get values from a `ArrayObject` just like a normal array. exp :

```
$friend_id = $resultSet['friend_id'];
```